# All attempts to reach EC2 instance time out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been struggling with this for two weeks. I am trying to set up an application in AWS, but cannot reach the EC2 instance. I've tried using the Visual Studio publication package, building an environment in EBS, building a server in EC2, connecting to the site via DNS and public IP, both in a browser and with ping, curl, trace route, and last with a RDC. I've tried nearly every combination of the above, and it seems like I am getting stuck on a firewall, somewhere. Trace route ends on 54 or 205, which belong to Amazon.

The obvious solution seems to be that I am not using security groups correctly, but nothing seems to work. I've tried opening up TCP, HTTP, SSH, HTTPS, UDP, and RDP, both to all addresses and my own IP, as well as opening up the scary All traffic from Anywhere. I usually just alter the group listed in the EC2 instance description, in the EC2 console, but have tried changing everything that is not an AWS group with the "Do not change or delete" warning.

I've only been developing for a couple of years, and assume that I'm missing something obvious, but I've never had this much trouble with hosting, and am completely stumped.

Comment: Security Groups are the normal cause of connection problems, but you seem to have ruled that out. Next, confirm that the instance has been launched in a Public Subnet. The easiest way to test this is to launch a new instance from the EC2 Quick Start page, and put that instance in the same subnet. Then try to connect to the new instance. If that works, then it is something specific to your original EC2 instance that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried building a new instance, but hit the same failures. My default Mac RDC, as well as the Windows RD for Mac, both failed to connect to the instance. A trace route tried to resolve, and got stuck on the same IPs they always do.

Comment: As other commenters pointed out, this is likely a security group issue. Take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html . Does that help ?

Comment: I've been through that, several times, in case I missed anything. Opening up RDP to my IP *should* be enough, and I've opened it up (as well as standard HTTP, etc... web protocols) to all traffic. The instance never seems to respond.

Comment: Ah, you're on a Mac! Are you trying to connect to Windows 2012 R2? If so, you have to use the newer "Microsoft Remote Desktop" with the red icon, available from the App Store. This is because 2012 R2 uses a different authentication method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I've tried both, and updated to the most recent version of Microsoft RD. Thanks for the input, though; I'll stop trying with RDC.

Comment: GOT IT.

I had my account deactivated some time ago, after RDS was building a new DB every hour, on the hour, and I couldn't figure out why (that was quite the bill).

When my account was reactivated, the Amazon employee didn't deactivate network throttling. So, every instance I created became unreachable after minimal traffic.